# com.scalar.db.exception.storage.NoMutationException: no mutation was applied. error when using ScalarDB

Tags: scalardb

The question is about Scalar DB (https://github.com/scalar-labs/scalardb).

The following code is giving `com.scalar.db.exception.storage.NoMutationException: no mutation was applied.` What causes this error and how can I fix it?

```
  def updateConfirmedStatusAndDeleteToken(user:User,token:UserToken) = Future {
    val transaction: DistributedTransaction = transactionService.start
    logger.trace("transaction started: " + transaction);
    //Perform the operations you want to group in the transaction

    val pUserKey = new Key(new IntValue("bucket", utilities.bucketIDFromEmail(user.profile.externalProfileDetails.email)),
      new TextValue("email", user.profile.externalProfileDetails.email)
    )
    val cUserKey = new Key(
      new TextValue("authprovider", "credentials"),
      new TextValue("firstname", user.profile.externalProfileDetails.firstName),
      new TextValue("lastname", user.profile.externalProfileDetails.lastName)
    )
    logger.trace("created keys. ")
    val putUser: Put = new Put(pUserKey, cUserKey)
      .forNamespace("cj")
      .forTable("users")
      .withValue(new BooleanValue("confirmed", true))

    logger.trace(s"putting user with confirmed status ${putUser}")
    transaction.put(putUser)
    logger.trace(s"reading token before deleting")
    val pGetToken = new Key(new TextValue("token_id",token.tokenId.toString))
    val getToken:Get = new Get(pGetToken)
      .forNamespace("cj")
      .forTable("user_authentication_token")

    transaction.get(getToken)

    logger.trace(s"deleting token. Preparing keys using ${token}, ${token.tokenId.toString}")
    val pDeleteTokenKey = new Key(new TextValue("token_id",token.tokenId.toString))
    logger.trace(s"delete key is ${pDeleteTokenKey}")
    val deleteToken:Delete = new Delete(pDeleteTokenKey)
      .forNamespace("cj")
      .forTable("user_authentication_token")

    transaction.delete(deleteToken)

    try{
      logger.trace(s"committing")
      transaction.commit()
    } catch {
      case e1:UnknownTransactionStatusException =>{
        logger.error("error in commiting. Unknowns status")
        throw e1;

      }
      case e2:CommitException =>{
        logger.error("error in commiting. Rolling back")
        transaction.abort();
        throw e2;
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was with my usage of DistributedTransaction. I was creating separate instances of DistributedTransaction for rather than using single one across different db operations. I created one in `updateConfirmedStatusAndDeleteToken` but similarly created new ones in other operations. Now I am passing the instance from the top level so that all operations use the same instance.